# conditionnal filling of a data table with the column names

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements

hello I guess this problem is easy for the R experts. I need to fill a data table with the name of the columns. The filling is depending on another column condition. Example :

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(V1=1:12, V2=c(1L,0L), V3=c(0L,1L,0L))
```

[image]

and the table I'm trying to obtain is :

[image]

thanks for the help

Comment: Shouldn't you do this at the data level (i.e. in the database itself)?   Just test the value in the field (`CASE [v2] WHEN 1 THEN 'v2' ELSE 'NA' END AS [V2.twin]`). I would suspect, then, that you only need a single field as it could be compacted down to say 'v2' or 'v3' and omit the 'NA'.  But, technically, you could just test the value of the field itself.  Your requirement seems a bit flaky.

Comment: Many thanks Paul for your answer and your reactivity. Unfortunatly, I'm not in the case I could directly change values in the database.

Comment: No worries.  Might be worth mentioning in your question, though (limitations of what you can do).  Good luck. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

1) using `for`:

```
cols <- c("V2", "V3")
for (x in cols)
    set(dt, dt[get(x)==1L, which=TRUE], paste0(x,".twin"), x)
```

2) Subsetting in `i` before updating by reference

```
for (x in cols)
    dt[get(x)==1L, paste0(x,".twin") := x]
```

3) indexing a vector

```
cols <- c("V2", "V3")
dt[, paste0(cols, ".twin") := Map(function(x, nm) c(NA_character_, nm)[x+1L], .SD, cols), .SDcols=cols]
```

4) using `ifelse`

```
dt[, paste0(cols, ".twin") := Map(function(x, nm) fifelse(x==1L, nm, NA_character_), .SD, cols), .SDcols=cols]
```

output:

```
    V1 V2 V3 V2.twin V3.twin
 1:  1  1  0      V2    <NA>
 2:  2  0  1    <NA>      V3
 3:  3  1  0      V2    <NA>
 4:  4  0  0    <NA>    <NA>
 5:  5  1  1      V2      V3
 6:  6  0  0    <NA>    <NA>
 7:  7  1  0      V2    <NA>
 8:  8  0  1    <NA>      V3
 9:  9  1  0      V2    <NA>
10: 10  0  0    <NA>    <NA>
11: 11  1  1      V2      V3
12: 12  0  0    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: Was about to post solution almost identical to 4)

Comment: Many thanks Chinsoon for your answer and your reactivity. This is exactly the solutions I need. All of them work. I'm not really easy with the 3rd. Why x+1 ?

Comment: c(0L, 1L) + 1L = c(1L, 2L) and the RHS is used to access the elements of c(NA, "V")